# A literal "*" in RestructuredText

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am looking at this snippet of code:

```
def ook(*args):
    """Some silly function.

    :param *args: Optional arguments.
    """
    ...
```

And as soon as I run Sphinx, I get the oh-so helpful error:

```
WARNING: Inline literal start-string without end-string.
```

So, I tried ``` param ``*``args ```, `param :literal:'*' args` and still get the warning.

*How do I have a literal '*' in restructuredText?*

Comment: your indentation is not actually like that?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: No, of course it is not.  ^_~

Comment: In this case, I would not include the asterisk in the param definition - it's not part of the parameter name

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use the (somewhat ugly) backslash quotation: `\*`

EDIT: As an (somewhat ugly) addendum, if you are concerned about pylint warning about the backslash, you could add a `r` to the string literal: `r""" ... docstring ... """`. This was descibed in [this pylint issue](https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issue/264/anomalous-backslash-in-string-warning-in).

Having different text processing systems play nicely together destroys sometimes the aesthetics.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this also happens with quotes, as in `""" a "comment """`, and can also be fixed with a backslash, like `""" a \"comment\" """"`.

Comment: In a Python docstring, you would need to use a raw string or escape the backslash (i.e. double it) so it is "seen" by Docutils.

Answer (score 1):

In restructuredtext you can use the .. code:: python directive.

http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#code

This allows you to create a literal block of python code without any ugly '\' characters.

It looks like this:

```
.. code:: python

    def ook(*args):
        """Some silly function.

        :param *args: Optional arguments.
        """
        ...
```

An example using your function is here:

http://rst.ninjs.org/?n=c8ad07eaea190745755a6d80d37786e6&theme=basic

Comment: This is for in-code documentation, so I want the "*" character in the doc string, not show the whole function/method.

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: in 2023 this is the only solution that worked for me. the accepted solution did not

Answer (score 1):

```
:param `*args`:
```

In addition to `\*`, the above works for me :)

Comment: This is a side-effect of Docutils not beeing able to parse nested inline markup: ```*args``` is interpreted as "default interpreted role" (which may or may not be what you want) and no parsing attempt is done inside.